# Why does password entering work in a piped sudo command?

Tags: linux, sudo, terminal, file-descriptors

If I do:

```
sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf | less
```

It will prompt me for the password, even though less (presumably) takes stdin. Over what fd's is the password prompt shown and how does it get the input back?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Actually, a typical invocation of `sudo` does not read the password from `stdin` at all. Instead, `sudo` will directly access the controlling terminal (a `tty` or `pty`, via the `/dev/tty` special file) and output the prompt and read characters directly. This can be seen in the `tgetpass.c` file in the `sudo` source.

There are a few other scenarios:

- If an `askpass` program is specified, e.g. in the `-A` param, that program will be invoked.
- Otherwise, if you specifically request `sudo` to read from `stdin`, e.g. with the `-S` flag -- and it will also write the prompt to `stderr`. This is the case where [MadHatter's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/731888) applies.
- Otherwise, if there is no `tty` available

  - If password echo is disabled (it is by default, controlled by the `visiblepw` flag in `sudoers`), `sudo` will report an error: `no tty present and no askpass program specified`
  - Otherwise, `sudo` will fall back to using `stdin` and `stderr` even if it was not specifically requested. [MadHatter's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/731888) will also apply here.

Answer (score 10):

The pipe connects `sudo cat`'s stdout to `less`'s stdin, so `sudo cat`'s stdin is unaffected, and able to receive the password.

As for the prompt, it goes out on `sudo cat`'s stderr; in bash, try redirecting that along with stdout, using

```
sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf |& less
```

and see how different the response is.

Comment: While this answer is correct in that `sudo`'s stdin is still connected to the terminal with the example command, that's not directly relevant to how it gets its password: by default `sudo` will not request passwords via stdin nor will it show the prompt via `stderr` -- you can try `2>/dev/null` to confirm that. Instead, `sudo` directly accesses the tty.