# Why is sudo password entering lost

Tags: linux, sudo, terminal, grep, pipelining

When I use `sudo command` and pipe it to another command, e.g.

```sh
sudo dnf search foo | grep bar
```

there is a prompt requiring to enter the password. Following [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/731886/why-does-password-entering-work-in-a-piped-sudo-command/731943), `sudo` directly accesses the terminal to prompt the password.

But I found that there are some programs which prevent that, for example `ripgrep`, when I type:

```sh
sudo dnf search foo | rg bar
```

there is no prompt for password, it's just blocked there.

How can this happen?